# It depends/ will depend/ would depend on something

Tags: modal-verbs

A: Is it "soccer" or "football"?

B:

1. I think "soccer" is more AmE, so it **depends** on who you're talking to.
2. I think "soccer" is more AmE, so it'**ll depend** on who you're talking to.
3. I think "soccer" is more AmE, so it **would depend** on who you're talking to.

Are they all correct? If so, what is the difference between 2) and 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 - You would say this if you know for certain they’re planning to talk to someone about this, or were making a strong assumption.

3 - You would say this if you were assuming they were thinking of talking to someone.

1 - This is the most general phrasing, and doesn’t really assume anything about them talking to someone, even though it references speaking to someone. It’s aligned more with phrasings like, “it depends who’s asking”, or, “it depends who your audience is”.

They’re all generally acceptable, but come with different “flavours” of presumptiveness.

Comment: You say: 2 - "*You would say this if you know for certain they’re planning to talk to someone about this, or **were making a strong assumption.***"----Assumption about what?

Comment: If you were making a strong assumption that they’d be talking to someone about it, as opposed to just asking the question out of a more general curiosity, for example.